# Does dimensionality reduction by SVD preserves the ranking order of the dot products between data vectors?

Tags: svd

I'm learning stanford cs224n.
In its [assignment 1](https://web.stanford.edu/class/cs224n/assignments/a1_preview/exploring_word_vectors.html), the notebook states:

> We obtain a full matrix decomposition, with the singular values ordered in the diagonal $S$ matrix, and our new, shorter length-$k$ word vectors in $U_k$.
>
> [image]
>
> This reduced-dimensionality co-occurrence representation preserves semantic relationships between words, e.g. *doctor* and *hospital* will be closer than *doctor* and *dog*.

So apparently the conclusion is *not* correct -- the reduced-dimensionality representation should be $U_k S_k$ rather than $U_k$ itself.
But even after the correction, it's still not always correct.
One may easily construct the following Python3 code to verify it:

```
import numpy as np
# used to extract non-duplicate elements from a symmetric matrix
from scipy.spatial.distance import squareform
# used to get the ranking order of elements
from scipy.stats import rankdata

# set parameters here
n = 10
d = 10
symmetriy = True
k = 7

# represents n d-dimensional vectors
A = np.random.randn(n, d)
if symmetry:
    A = A.T @ A

U, S, _ = np.linalg.svd(A, full_matrices=False)
Uk, Sk = U[:, :k], S[:k]

# (i, j) element of these three matrices is the dot product between the
# i-th vector in A or Uk or Uk*Sk and j-th vector in A or Uk or Uk*Sk
Adot = squareform(A @ A.T, checks=False)
Udot = squareform(Uk @ Uk.T, checks=False)
USdot = squareform((Uk * Sk) @ (Uk * Sk).T, checks=False)

# the ranking order
rAdot = rankdata(Adot)
rUdot = rankdata(Udot)
rUSdot = rankdata(USdot)

assert np.allclose(rAdot, rUdot)    # note (*)
assert np.allclose(rAdot, rUSdot)   # note (**)
```

where `(*)` is always false, and the value of `(**)` depends:

- When `n` equals `d`, `n` is small and `symmetry` is true, `(**)` is *mostly* true;
- Otherwise, `(**)` is almost always false.

Here is my attempt to dervie the general form of conclusion (i.e. when `n` is not equal to `d`):
Let the data matrix be $\mathbf A \in \mathbb R^{n \times d}$.
Let $\mathbf A = \mathbf U\mathbf S\mathbf V^\top$ be the SVD.
Then the dot-product matrix of $\mathbf A$ is:

$$
\mathbf A\mathbf A^\top = \sum_{i=1}^n \sigma_i^2 \boldsymbol u_i \boldsymbol u_i^\top
$$

where $\sigma_i^2$'s are the descendingly sorted squared singular values, and $\boldsymbol u_i$'s are the left singular vectors.
The dot-product matrix of the reduced-dimensionality data matrix $U_k S_k$ is:

$$
(\mathbf U_k \mathbf S_k)(\mathbf U_k \mathbf S_k)^\top = \sum_{i=1}^k \sigma_i^2 \boldsymbol u_i \boldsymbol u_i^\top
$$

Let $\boldsymbol e_i$ be the $i$-th column of an identity matrix of appropriate dimension.
To preserve the ranking order of elements of $\mathbf A \mathbf A^\top$, the following statement must hold:

$$
\forall p_1,q_1,p_2,q_2,\ 
\boldsymbol e_{p_1}^\top \mathbf A \mathbf A^\top \boldsymbol e_{q_1} \ge \boldsymbol e_{p_2}^\top \mathbf A \mathbf A^\top \boldsymbol e_{q_2}
\Rightarrow \boldsymbol e_{p_1}^\top (\mathbf U_k \mathbf S_k)(\mathbf U_k \mathbf S_k)^\top \boldsymbol e_{q_1} \ge \boldsymbol e_{p_2}^\top (\mathbf U_k \mathbf S_k)(\mathbf U_k \mathbf S_k)^\top \boldsymbol e_{q_2} \tag{1}
$$

But from the above experiment, it does not necessarily hold.

Hence my question relaxes to:

1. Either: given that $\boldsymbol e_{p_1}^\top \mathbf A \mathbf A^\top \boldsymbol e_{q_1} \ge \boldsymbol e_{p_2}^\top \mathbf A \mathbf A^\top \boldsymbol e_{q_2}$, what's the lower bound of $\boldsymbol e_{p_1}^\top (\mathbf U_k \mathbf S_k)(\mathbf U_k \mathbf S_k)^\top \boldsymbol e_{q_1} \ge \boldsymbol e_{p_2}^\top (\mathbf U_k \mathbf S_k)(\mathbf U_k \mathbf S_k)^\top \boldsymbol e_{q_2}$?
2. Or: what additional condition the singular values should hold in order for (1) to hold?

Any suggestions are appreciated!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I starts to feel that in "This reduced-dimensionality co-occurrence representation preserves semantic relationships between words", it probably does not mean to preserve *all* inner product, but to preserve inner products *as much as possible*. This is, indeed, the job of SVD.

To conclude this question, I wrote a [post](https://kkew3.github.io/2023/10/06/dimensionality-reduction-by-svd.html) on how SVD performs dimensionality reduction.